# d3 v4 scaleBand ticks

Tags: d3.js

I have data like the following

```
date,values
2016-10-01,10
2016-10-02,20
2016-10-03,30
2016-10-04,5
2016-10-05,50
2016-10-06,2
2016-10-07,7
2016-10-08,17
```

and am generating a bar chart using the following code

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var tip = d3.tip()
.attr('class', 'd3-tip')
.offset([-10, 0])
.html(function(d) {
return "<strong>Month of " + d.date + ":</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.value + " sales</span>";
})

var svg = d3.select("#barg").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.call(tip);
data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre#data2").text());
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.value = +d.value;
});

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" )

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Value ($)");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth() - 5)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

So the problem I am having is that I have ordinal data, but for large cardinality (for instance, 120 data points) The x axis has way too many ticks.  I have tried a few things like `tickValues`, but when I use this, my x axis tick points all show up on top of each other.  Ideally I would like 10 tick points or so, when the cardinality is high.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 34):

This can be done using `tickValues` indeed. For instance, in this demo, we have 200 values, so the axis is absolutely crowded:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 100);

var data = d3.range(200);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d}))
  .range([10, 490]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var gX = svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, the same code using `tickValues`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 100);

var data = d3.range(200);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d}))
  .range([10, 490]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d,i){ return !(i%10)}));

var gX = svg.append("g").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

In this last snippet, `tickValues` uses the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) to show only 1 in every 10 ticks:

```
.tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d,i){ 
    return !(i%10)
}));
```

Comment: I am trying to use your code to adapt mine.  Do you know why my tick values are all on top of each other on the x axis?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using a JS date, but you're not using a time scale. Try to remove `d.date = parseDate(d.date);` and see what happens.

Comment: Actually if you don't mind I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x1q8xtt/), can you take a look at it?

Comment: Ahh wait, I may have figured it out now.  I removed the parseDate function, and added <code>return d.date</code> to the domain.  Thanks it works great now!

Comment: i keep on getting tickValues it not a function??

Comment: @doyz I suggest you post a question with the relevant details.

Comment: Can we start from 1 instead if 0 in xAxis. I tried using tickFormat but it didn't return expected result

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general solution to this problem using `tickFormat(...)`. We can define a minimum acceptable width for our ticks, then skip every *n*th tick based on this minimum.

```js
d3
    .axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickFormat((t, i) => {
        const MIN_WIDTH = 30;
        let skip = Math.round(MIN_WIDTH * data.length / chartWidth);
        skip = Math.max(1, skip);

        return (i % skip === 0) ? t : null;
    });
```

`let skip = ...` is a rearrangement of the inequality `ChartWidth / (NumTicks / N) > MinWidth`. Here `N` represents the tick "step size", so we are asserting that the width of every *n*th tick is greater than the minimum acceptable width. If we rearrange the inequality to solve for `N`, we can determine how many ticks to skip to achieve our desired width.

Comment: That is a very useful piece of code! The problem for me is now to dynamically determine MIN_WIDTH given different axis labels and different font sizes. And how to measure text width of text that has not yet been rendered... I will stick with a constant for now but too big a value may drop too many labels.