# Specifying Ticks on D3 Bar chart with Time Series data and scaleBand

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to specify a number of ticks and a number of tick labels for a d3 v4 bar chart with time series data as shown in the following image:

[image]

Based on [this tutorial](https://bl.ocks.org/zigahertz/1ee4965ff76514517bb7ce6af21e5d44) I've got a bar chart working with time series data, but I cannot get the ticks to display the way I want. For example, to show every 10th tick to leave room for the label. Any help is greatly appreciated!

@prmko
Thanks for your responses. I've seen both of the posts you referenced in the comments, but applying the solution with the tickValues removes the ticks from the x-axis altogether, which led me to conclude that my situation is somehow different. This is why I commented out the tickValues line in my code snippet. I'd love to be wrong though, perhaps I'm not reading the solution correctly. Can you provide a working example that implements this approach? Thanks for your help.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.isoParse

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width], .05).padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"))
    //.tickValues(x.domain().filter(function(d, i) {return !(i%4);}));
 
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(4);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {
var data = [
  {
    "date": "2016-03-02T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "53"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-03T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "165"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-04T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "269"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-05T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "344"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-06T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "376"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-07T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "410"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-08T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "421"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-09T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "405"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-10T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "376"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-11T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "359"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-12T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "392"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-13T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "433"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-14T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "455"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-15T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "478"
  }
];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

// });
```

```css
 .axis {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
 }

 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3 v4 scaleBand ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199108/d3-v4-scaleband-ticks)

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013290/how-to-parse-date-on-d3-with-a-specific-interval?noredirect=1#comment85072448_49013290). Probably more accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your snippet. When specifying `.tickValues(x.domain().filter(function(d,i){ return !(i%10)}));`, the x scale domain must be set, which it was not yet when its called in your original snippet. I moved the axis creation to after the domain is set and it works.

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.isoParse

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width], .05).padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(4);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {
var data = [
  {
    "date": "2016-03-02T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "53"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-03T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "165"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-04T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "269"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-05T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "344"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-06T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "376"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-07T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "410"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-08T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "421"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-09T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "405"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-10T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "376"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-11T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "359"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-12T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "392"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-13T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "433"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-14T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "455"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-03-15T00:00:00-05:00",
    "value": "478"
  }
];
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d"))
    .tickValues(x.domain().filter(function(d,i){ return !(i%4)}));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

// });
```

```css
 .axis {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
 }

 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"  charset="utf-8"></script>
```