# D3 Line Graph -- Line x-axis calculated by day while x-axis labels are by month

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3 line graph currently calculating both the line x-axis and the x-axis labels by month. In the screenshot below, I have two different dates in the same month. Currently they display with the same x-axis value:

[image]

I want the x-axis line to calculate by days while the labels remain months. See relevant code below:

```
<script>
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  let eventSourceArr = [];
                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/diary',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                      console.log('Diary GET success');
                      console.log('data: ',data);

                      //Need to show days, not just months, in the graph
                      for (let i in data.data) {

                        //Convert UNIX time to date
                        let a = new Date(data.data[i].created_at*1000);
                        let year = a.getFullYear();
                        year = year.toString();
                        year = year.slice(2);
                        let month = a.getMonth();
                        month = month.toString();
                        if (month.length === 1) {
                          month = '0' + month;
                        }
                        let date = a.getDate();
                        date = date.toString();
                        if (date.length === 1) {
                          date = '0' + date;
                        }
                        let formattedTime = month + '/' + year;

                        eventSourceArr.push({"feeling": data.data[i].feeling, "month": formattedTime});
                        console.log('eventSourceArr: ',eventSourceArr);
                      }

                      let sixMonthsAgo;
                      let yearSixMonthsAgo;

                      if ((parseInt(moment().format('MM')) - 6) > 0) {
                        sixMonthsAgo = parseInt(moment().format('M') - 6);
                        yearSixMonthsAgo = parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'));
                      }
                       else if ((parseInt(moment().format('MM')) - 6) <= 0) {
                        sixMonthsAgo = parseInt(moment().format('M')) + 6;
                        yearSixMonthsAgo = parseInt(moment().format('YYYY')) - 1;
                      };

                      let vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
                          WIDTH = 1000,
                          HEIGHT = 475,
                          MARGINS = {
                              top: 20,
                              right: 20,
                              bottom: 20,
                              left: 50
                          },
                          xScale = d3.time.scale()
                            .domain([new Date(yearSixMonthsAgo, sixMonthsAgo, 1), new Date()])
                            .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]),
                          yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([1, 10]),
                          xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(xScale)
                            .orient("bottom")
                            .ticks(d3.time.months)
                            .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B")),
                          yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(yScale)
                            .orient("left");

                      vis.append("svg:g")
                          .attr("class", "x axis")
                          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                          .call(xAxis);
                      vis.append("svg:g")
                          .attr("class", "y axis")
                          .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                          .call(yAxis);


                      let lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) {
                              // let formatDate = d3.time.format("%-m/%y");
                              let formatDate = d3.time.format("%-j");
                              let monthData = formatDate.parse(d.month);
                              console.log('formatDate: ',formatDate);
                              console.log('monthData: ',monthData);
                              return xScale(monthData);
                              // return xScale(d.created_at);
                          })
                          .y(function(d) {
                              return yScale(parseInt(d.feeling));
                          })
                          .interpolate("basis");
                      vis.append('svg:path')
                          .attr('d', lineGen(eventSourceArr))
                          .attr('stroke', 'blue')
                          .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                          .attr('fill', 'none');

                      },
                      error: function() {
                        console.log('Diary GET failure');
                      }
                  });
              });
            </script>
```

The raw `data.data` object looks like this:

```
{"id": 2, "feeling": 3, "notes": "Had a bad day", "updated_at": 1520273147, "created_at": 1520273147}
```

The x-axis line is visualizing `"created_at"`. There are two data items in the screenshot, both different dates in February.

How do I change this?

EDIT: Added entire script instead of sections.

Comment: You're only returning the month data in your `lineGen` function for x. It seems from you time format string that you data only contains month and year. Could we see some example data? I can only tell that your times look like `2/17`

Comment: I added the code you requested.

Comment: It looks like you have nice date objects but are then forcing them to be only `month/year`. Pass the entire date to js and you won't lose the day portion of it. d3's time scale will happily plot it for you. Just format the axis the way to want but don't change the underlying data as you are losing the resolution.

Comment: That's what I was just going to say... in your `x(...)` function, remove the date/month formatting stuff and simply `return xScale(d.created_at);`

Comment: When I only have `return xScale(d.created_at);` in the `x(...)` function, the line disappears. Should anything else still be in that function?

The problem is that when I leave the date info as Unix then the labels get messed up. They turn into a mess of black text superimposed all over itself.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034919/specifying-ticks-on-d3-bar-chart-with-time-series-data-and-scaleband/49035433#49035433). This is for v4. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/f92e3d68d0d910af7f8c8ff87f5b2468) is a v3 example that may help.

Comment: My experience with D3 is such that I still can't quite figure it out...

Comment: Quick question: do you have to use v3? Can you use v4?

Comment: Sure, I'm not necessarily tied to either. My D3 is really weak, so I've largely constructed the code I have from Stack Overflow posts and examples elsewhere to do what I want. As such, I probably only really understand ~80% of it.

Comment: If you could post more data and more code that would be super helpful. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added the full script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code into v4 and did no parsing of times, created a fake second data point for show purposes. Axis are not perfect as I only have 2 data points but this should get you in the right direction.

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 2,
    "feeling": 3,
    "notes": "Had a bad day",
    "updated_at": 1520273147000,
    "created_at": 1520273147000
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "feeling": 5,
    "notes": "Had a bad day",
    "updated_at": 1520273287000,
    "created_at": 1520273287000
  }
];

let vis = d3.select("#visualization"),
  WIDTH = 1000,
  HEIGHT = 475,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
  xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([1520273146000, 1520273288000])
  .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]),
  yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([1, 10]);
vis.attr("height", HEIGHT).attr('width', WIDTH)
vis.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")));
vis.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

let lineGen = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(+d.created_at);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(+d.feeling);
  });

vis.datum(data).append('path')
  .attr("class", "genLine")
  .attr('d', lineGen)
  .attr('stroke', 'blue')
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<svg id='visualization'></svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Wonderful. I think this is close enough to what I want that I can work it out. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I'd say if you're just starting d3 and not tied to v3 use v4, Most of the syntax is easier and the docs aren't too bad.